# Poker Frequencies calculation

Tags: combinatorics

I'm confused about the choice of Combinatorial to calculate the frequencies of poker hands.
For example, to calculate the number ways in which we can get a full house

$$\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$
I understand this to be: from 13 kinds, choose 1, from the 4 cards in this kind choose 3; from the remaining 12 kinds choose 1, and from the 4 cards in this kind choose 2.

Following this logic I would calculate the frequency for 2 pairs as:

$$\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{1}$$

But I found online that the actual answer is:

$$\binom{13}{2} \left[\binom{4}{2}\right]^2\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{1}$$

So my question is: when can I group my choices together and when can I do it one at a time?
Because this last calculation seems to imply: from 13 kinds choose the 2 to make pairs, from each of those kinds choose 2... then why can't I say for full house: "from 13 kinds choose 2, and from one of them choose 3 and from the other choose 2"? The numerical answers are VERY different in both cases

Comment: The reason the first formula gives too large a number is that it counts $\heartsuit 4\clubsuit4 \spadesuit Q\diamondsuit Q\clubsuit 3$ as a different combination than $\spadesuit Q\diamondsuit Q\heartsuit 4\clubsuit 4\clubsuit 3$. But in reality these should only count as one combination no matter how you shuffle the five cards among themselves. There are lots of questions here that are essentially the same, "Why can't I count the ways to choose ____ and then count the ways to choose ____".